# ASP bind SQL time(5) in format HH:mm

Tags: sql, asp.net, time, formatting

I have a SQL DB data binding to a formview and am trying to format a time(5) filed to an HH:mm format.
I have no problem formatting a date field but can't find a format for the time field.

```
            <asp:TextBox ID="End_DateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("End_Date", "{0:dddd dd MMMM yyyy}") %>' Width="320px"/>
            <br />
             <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Start_time:" Width="90px"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="Start_timeTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Start_time", "{0:HH:mm}") %>' Width="80px"/>
```

I nave tried many variations and get 'Input string was not in a correct format. " with all

Comment: I think value of Start_time is null

Comment: Thanks for thought..but not the case. When I run with no formatting the value displays as 09:00:00 ie. nine oclock am